# Calculating ratio of bicarbonate ion to carbonic acid in blood

Tags: everyday-chemistry

For the following reaction, $\ce{K_a} = \pu{4.2e-7}$ :

$\ce{H2CO3(aq) + H2O(l) <=> H3O+(aq) + HCO3-(aq)}$

We're given the pH of blood, which is $7.4$. We need to calculate the ratio ("$X$") of bicarbonate ion to carbonic acid in blood.

I know I need to convert the $\ce{K_a}$ to $\ce{pK_a}$, and did so as follows:

$\ce{pK_a} = -\log(\ce{K_a}) = -\log(\pu{4.2e-7}) = 6.4$

But I'm not sure how to proceed from here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you familiar with the [Henderson–Hasselbalch equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henderson%E2%80%93Hasselbalch_equation)?

Answer (score 1):

For these types of problems, the general approach would be to use the Henderson-Hasselbalch equation. For a general weak acid/conjugate base system, this has the form: $$\mathrm{pH}=\mathrm pK_\mathrm a+\lg\left(\frac{\ce{A-}}{\ce{HA}}\right)$$ Since you are given $\mathrm{pH}$ and have found $\mathrm pK_\mathrm a$, it won't require much more work to obtain the ratio.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Henderson-Hasselbalch equation

$$\mathrm{pH} = \mathrm{p}K_{\mathrm{a}} + \log_{10}\left({[\ce{A-}]\over[\ce{HA}]}\right)$$

and substituting bicarbonate and carbonic acid for $\ce{A-}$ and $\ce{HA}$, respectively, we arrive at:

$$\mathrm{pH} = \mathrm{p}K_{\mathrm{a}} + \log_{10}\left({[\ce{HCO3-}]\over[\ce{H2CO3}]}\right)$$

Given $\mathrm{pH}$ for blood and computing $\mathrm{p}K_{\mathrm{a}} = 6.376$ from the information given, we have

$$7.4 = 6.376 + \log_{10}\left({[\ce{HCO3-}]\over[\ce{H2CO3}]}\right)$$

or

$$1.024 = \log_{10}\left({[\ce{HCO3-}]\over[\ce{H2CO3}]}\right)$$

Finally, the ratio of bicarbonate to carbonic acid is solved for as

$$10^{1.024} = \left({[\ce{HCO3-}]\over[\ce{H2CO3}]}\right) = 10.57$$

which makes sense at given that the $\mathrm{pH}$ for blood is almost exactly one unit higher than the $\mathrm{p}K_{\mathrm{a}}$ for carbonic acid.